# UML Designer model from Java

Tags: uml-designer

I would like to initialize a model from an existing Java source code.

Is there an option to do it in Obeo UML Designer ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As UML Designer is based on the Eclipse UML2 project you can install the Eclipse UML Gen plugins: https://www.eclipse.org/umlgen/

One of these plugins will allow you to get a reverse engineering tool.

These plugins are not part of UML Designer but I will try in the future to ease the installation. An issue already exists about this in our tracker : https://github.com/ObeoNetwork/UML-Designer/issues/878